# purchases_flutter MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

i've implemented purchases_flutter on my app as wrote in the docs but when i try to call any methods (setDebugLogsEnabled, setupPurchases, getOfferings) the console return the MissingPluginException. This exception happens only on android (BILLING is in the manifest).
purchases_flutter is in the dependencies, flutter clean done, i've deleted the pub-cache and i've tryed to create a new project, but nothing worked. Any idea ?

Solved: I'm not 100% sure but i think the problem was flutter_barcode_scanner, i've made a brand new project without that package and the exception disappeared.

Comment: have you added ```<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
``` in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata yes

Comment: please have a look into that https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter#requirements

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata as i said i've red the docs and i've purchases_flutter in the dependencies and BILLING in the Manifest but still it doesn't work. I don't see any other requirement.

Comment: Can you run the sample app in https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter successfully?

Comment: @Cesar the sample app works, also works in a different app. Cloud be a specific package to cause the exception?